# Pull-up bar hanged from drywall door-frame

Tags: drywall, walls

I bought a pull-up/chin-up [bar](https://www.amazon.de/Klimmzugstange-Befestigung-Oberk%C3%B6rpertrainer-Hochwertigen-Schaumstoffgriffen/dp/B01L45V6HA/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1534668418&sr=8-3&keywords=Klimmzugstange&refinements=p_72%3A419117031) to hang from my door frame.

The instructions state that it is not to be used for walls made out of drywall/rigips. The hollow noise I hear when knocking on said wall though makes me believe that is exactly what it is made out of. This goes for all the door frames in my flat. One such door-frame looks like this, from either side:
[image]

[image]

The building is from 2007, so I suspect that door frames in most other new buildings are enclosed in similar types of walls. Thus, I cannot imagine that this pull-up bar is only to be used in the very few cases where the door frame is encased in a non-drywall (concrete) wall.

How much of a risk would it be to use the bar with this kind of soft wall? My weight (80kg) is well under the maximum load of the bar itself (150 kg), so the worry is really just about damage done to the drywall itself, assuming this is where most of the force will be dissipated (and not onto the door-frame sides).

Comment: Can you post a pic of the door frame you want to use?  Based on pics of the bar it looks like it's designed to hang off the door trim.  Door trim is usually attached to door frames (wooden) with trim nails and are not load bearing.

Comment: Yes - should have posted that from the beginning .. will take a pic now

Comment: I'm attempting to do the same. How did it go for you?

Comment: went well, no troubles at all!

Answer (score 4):

While it is touching the door trim, technically it is not  mounted to or attached to the door trim, or the wall for that matter. One side is pushing against the door trim attached to the jamb and framing behind it and the other side is pushing against its trim  and door jamb and framing,  this creates a situation where leverage is being used to push both sides towards each other.  The weight of the person using it causes the two opposing sides to push harder against each other there by pinning it to the door jamb and wall framing.

I suppose the risk would be that if the rough opening behind the trim (  The space between the wall framing and the door jamb ) is of a significant gap than the forces pushing against the trim would push the drywall into that void  causing it to crack.

You could remove the trim from the door and inspect the framing and jamb behind it. You could also replace the trim with a more robust material such as a hardwood  that is wider than your average trim to spread out the force is pushing against the wall.

Personally I would just try it, any properly constructed door framing should be sufficient and since I can’t read the German Amazon link I can’t know the specific instructions for this unit.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I could just try and put progressively higher pressure on the bar (lifting myself up) - if it does not hold, there should be warning signs before any damage is done. I've added a picture of the wall in question, in case it is helpful with the advice...

Comment: That trim looks fairly robust and wide so I’d say you’re good L.